# Connect from a GCP project to an instance in an AWS VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

I am considering establishing a hybrid cloud setup at my workplace. Right now, we have machine learning jobs running on a Spark cluster on AWS. What I want to do is to be able to connect to that cluster from an Airflow job running on GCP, in order to invoke various jobs as needed and perform other tasks.

I don't know how to do that, though. I could create a public DNS for the Spark cluster which would make it easy to connect from GCP over the Internet, but I assume that isn't ideal for security.

Do I need to setup a VPN between the GCP project (i.e. GCP VPC) and the AWS VPC? If so, how can I do that? I don't want to use a 3rd party product if there's a way to do this with vanilla GCP and AWS configuration.

Basically, I think what I need is for the job on GCP to be able to see the internal DNS of the Spark cluster and be able to use that to connect, but again I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Both AWS and GCP have the concepts of VPN.  I followed this recipe in the past to set up private networking between the two.

https://cloud.google.com/files/CloudVPNGuide-UsingCloudVPNwithAmazonWebServices.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Ther are several factors to consider.

1. VPC addressing (CIDR blocks). They cannot overlap.
2. GCP to/from AWS VPN. This is easy to setup.
3. DNS resolution. Both VPCs have their own DNS. To set up forwarders and resolvers between GCP and AWS VPCs is challenging. I recommend ignoring this feature and use private IP addresses if possible.
4. Cost. You will need a VPN gateway on both sides which has an hourly cost and a bandwidth cost.
5. Security. Both VPCs have security group rules. Be careful with routing rules so that you don't accidentally send Internet traffic over the VPN.

Summary:

Your requirements are very easy to achieve except for split DNS name resolution. Double-check pricing so that you do not have any surprises.